# Problem with script in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Am trying to write a script that tests to see if my vpn is connected. When run, the script currently only echos the vpn status. Eventually, I want the script to do much more, but for now, I am trying to work out the testing bit and it's driving me up the wall. No matter what status the VPN is in, the script always reports as "Not Connected".

The command I am using to check status is `nordvpn status` but that spits out more lines of information than I am looking for, so I grep out the line that reports its connection status. Here is the raw output from `nordvpn status` when connected.

```
You are connected to NordVPN.
Current server: us1681.nordvpn.com
Your new IP: xxx.xxx.200.1xx
Current protocol: UDP
Transfer: 1.7 MB received, 500.5 KB sent
```

This is the output from `nordvpn status` when I am not connected.

`You are not connected to NordVPN.`

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
NORDSTAT1="$(nordvpn status | grep connected)"
if [ "$NORDSTAT1 = 'You are not connected to NordVPN.'" ]; then
    echo  Not Connected
else
    echo Connected
fi
```

If I add a line to the script that says `echo $NORDSTAT1`, it shows that the connection status is correctly stored in the variable. Also, I have confirmed that the string that I am testing against is an exact match of the grep'd line from `nordvpn status`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `nordvpn status` however I did something similar to this (I was just checking for internet connection `netctl status interface`). You might try checking the return value of the command. It is likely (assuming they're sane people at nordvpn) different if you are connected vs unconnected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoting in the script is wrong. The expression in the line

```
if [ "$NORDSTAT1 = 'You are not connected to NordVPN.'" ]; then
```

is *one* complete string that gets interpolated (variable resolved) to

```
if [ "You are not connected to NordVPN. = 'You are not connected to NordVPN.'" ]; then
```

This simply checks whether that string is non-empty. You want

```
if [ "$NORDSTAT1" = "You are not connected to NordVPN." ]; then
```

instead to test for equality of the *two* strings.

---

The test could also be rewritten with `grep -q`. It tests for the existence
of a pattern *without printing*. Instead, the result can be determined from
`grep`'s returncode (which is `0` for *found* and `!=0` for *not found*).
In that case the test must changed a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if nordvpn status | grep -q "not connected"; then
    echo "Not Connected"  # the string "not connected" is contained in the output
else
    echo "Connected"      # ... is not contained
fi
```

I think it's just a matter of taste in this case, though.